# How to test a custom function in a directive angular 2+

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have following directive where I have some custom private functions

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAccessPermission]'
})
export class AccessPermissionDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() claims: string[];
  @Input() shouldAllClaimsRequired = true;
  @Input() shouldDisableThanHide = true;


  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private authService: AuthenticationService , private helper: JwtHelperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkClaims();
  }

  checkClaims() {
// Do some logic
}
}
```

However I am unable to unit test the checkclaims or ngoninit functions

I have added following code in the beforeEach Method

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [AccessPermissionDirective, DirectiveTestComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: ElementRef, useClass: MockElementRef},
    {provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService},
    JwtHelperService,
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DirectiveTestComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

Here the component. have access to all the @Input variables. However no access to ngOnInit and checkClaims functions.

Any idea how do I get the access and test them individually.

I even try getting it with `fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(AccessPermissionDirective));` with no luck.

Comment: Are you wanting access to the method because you are trying to invoke those explicitly inside the test or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I want to access them individually inside the test, something like `component.checkClaims()` I am able to assign @input variables like `componet.claims = []` . Then my question is why can't I do the former.

Comment: Well if you are trying to access something private there is always the possibility of using something like (element as any).privatePropOrMethod. But neither onInit nor your checkClaims seem to be marked as private. Have you made sure that you are actually trying to call those methods on the directive? What is the exact error?